# Trying to setup a Simple Addition Sequence using Random Generator

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to set up a simple addition sequence using the random generator. The number has to be an int.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

(4, 10, 16, 22, 28, ?) : the user must input the next number in the sequence. (it is 34 because each number is 6 numbers apart from one another.)

The user is given random numbers from the generator, but the 2 numbers next to each other must have the same value for the distance apart as the next two. Ex: 10-4 = 6,   16-10 = 6,  22-16 = 6.

```
private static void simpleAdditionSequence() {
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, numUser;
    Random generator = new Random();

    num1 = generator.nextInt(2147483647);
    System.out.println(num1);
}
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to create num2. If I just use another generator it could be less than num1, and it needs to have the same value for its distance apart as the rest of the numbers.

(Note - I used 2147483647 so I can generate random INTEGERS.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, questions on SO aren't tagged with "[solved]" in the title, but you should accept the best answer.

Comment: @MJ93: two minor nitpicks...   In Java writing *Integer.MAX_VALUE* is less error prone and better conveys the "intent" than writing *"2147483647"*.  Then if you really insist on picking your step using *nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)* then you'll want to actually use *long* to solve your problem because a solution using *int* will break when the step is big (with *int* you'd be quickly "wrapping over" and be dealing with negative values).

Comment: Thank you, I learned that I don't have to use ANY integer value, I can set it as a limit to something like: 100. But that is good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only two numbers in your problem are actually *random* -- the first number and the difference between numbers.

Generate *two* random integers; one for the base, one for the step, and be content.

(One thing to look out for -- you should only ever create *one* random-number-generator in your program. Re-use that generator every time you need random numbers. If you create a new generator every time you need a random number, your numbers will not have the randomness properties you desire.)

Comment: Thanks I figured it out before you posted. Like you said, my first number and the difference between them are the only randoms. I can just add my first number to the difference, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

First off, `nextInt()` only returns int data types.

Second, if it's a pattern that you are ultimately generating then you'd only need to generate the first number and then the difference between it and the second and from there you could calculate the remaining digits yourself. To use your example:

`num1 = generator.nextInt(2147483647);` stores the number `4` in the variable `num1`. Then you generate a random incremental value, let's say you call the `nextInt()` method again and you get `6` stored in your `increment` variable. Then:

```
num2 = num1 + increment; // 4 + 6 = 10
num3 = num2 + increment; // 10 + 6 = 16
// Etc...
```